# Add ignored config file to git repo as sample

Tags: git

I have an repository for an app that I'm working on that includes a configuration file. Currently, I distribute with a `.dist` extension, and have the user rename the file before editing it.

```
nate:~/myAwesomeApp% git ls-files 
.gitignore
README
config.dist
glorious_support_lib.p
bestProgramEvar.f90
```

This is fine and dandy, and the actual config is ignored.

```
nate:~/myAwesomeApp% cat .gitignore 
config
```

It would be **sweet**, however, if I could just distribute that config file under its real name and ready-to-edit, while leaving it ignored so that a newly cloned copy of the repository has a "functional" distribution, and it is not overwritten, clobbered, or otherwise molested, and such that users don't have to worry about pushing or publishing their **super-secret** configuration details to the interwebs via an unintended `git commit -a -m 'hurrrr derp! oopsies!' && git push`

Is there a way of doing this? Of having git keep around a single original version of the file that gets cloned out, but is *thereafter* ignored?

I'm sure this has been asked before, but for the life of me, my google-fu has failed. Lay the schoolin' on deep, SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also version and distribute:

- a `.gitattributes` files declaring a **[filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)** (for only 'config.dist')
- a smudge script which will detect that content and generate the final (and private, as in "non-versioned" `config` file)

Now that is bending a bit what a filter driver is about (it is about modifying the content of a file, [regardless of its "state", i.e its full path and name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562523/using-git-to-work-with-subversion-ignoring-modifications-to-tracked-files/2562678#2562678)). But it can work.
The `.gitattributes` would contain:

```
config.dist  filter=generateConfig
```

[image]

And you can register your smudge script (applied during the checkout step when creating/updating the working directory) like:

```
git config --global filter.generateConfig.smudge /path/to/generateConfig
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd probably include an 'install' script of some sort that copied 'config.dist' to 'config'.

I don't think there's a way to have a file both not-ignored and ignored.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing now. It would just be sweet if there were an "ignore after commit xxxxxx" ability.

Comment: @sleepynate Maybe a post commit hook checking the commit xxxxxx and adding something to .gitignore?

Answer (score 4):

This is a good question, but AFAIK there is no git solution for this.

Few workarounds:

- configure your app to read `config.dist` when `config` is not present (e.g. PHPUnit uses this technique)
- use build script to do rename for you (e.g. ant or phing)
- use git hooks to rename the configs

Comment: I think `post-checkout` runs on clone.. but does the hook come down with the repo on initial clone? How does that look?

Comment: @sleepynate This will be hard to do. Just tested - hooks are not cloned with the repo on `git clone [repo]`. I thought about git hooks used during development. I didn't consider cloning as a distribution technique of the app.

Comment: Oh sorry. I will edit for clarity. This is for the end user when they clone. i already have an `if [ ! -e config ] ; then cp config.dist config ; fi`

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, there is no magical solution for this in Git. And as far as I know, it's the same with other version control systems.

Hooks are also of no solution here, if they would work this way, that would be a serious security threat - just by cloning a repo, an evil code could execute in your machine.

But to use your app, the user has to do at least one more thing besides cloning it with git: running your app.

- If modifying the config file **is not** required for running the application, then if your program does `if [ ! -e config ] ; then cp config.dist config ; fi` on startup, then that should be IMHO quite enough. Additionally you should have warning inside `config.dist` which says you shouldn't modify this file, but make a copy of it instead.
- If the modification of config file **is** required, then starting the program without config file could start up some installation mode, that asks the user to enter the needed configuration options and saves them.
- A third possibility is that your app is **unable** to modify the config file when it starts up (maybe it's just some JavaScript + HTML files). In that case I see no other option than to have some separate build script or let the user just manually do it.