# Something like gitignore but not git ignore

Tags: git, github

I want to ignore a file containing database-passwords and such. I asked a friend who set up the git if I could us gitignore. He said "no, because there is already a file with dummy data in the repository, there is another function that you should use, I don't remember what it's called, google it!"

I tried googleing, but given the information it's pretty tricky, does anyone know what function he is talking about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a [gitattribute filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728)

[image]

That way:

- on the checkout step, a 'smudge' script can replace the content of your file by whatever you want, saving its original content first (that is, assuming the content of that file is specific enough to be detected as the right content, [since a filter driver is about the *content* of files, not about a specific file pathname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562523/using-git-to-work-with-subversion-ignoring-modifications-to-tracked-files/2562678#2562678)).
- and/or on the commit step, a 'clean' script can restore the same file in its original content (again assuming the modified content is specific enough to be detected and replaced)

Answer (score 13):

If you add the file to .git/info/exclude - it will ignored, and this exclude file is local to your repository and will not be available to others.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to gitignore:

[Ignore the .gitignore file itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767147/how-do-i-tell-git-to-ignore-gitignore/767219#767219)

Comment: The link was good - but please always provide relevant pieces in the answer itself rather than throwing in a link alone.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore files that are already tracked, use this:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <filePath>
```

Comment: Hi @framontb

This approach can introduce some confusion for team members who might not realize that the file is being excluded from commits. Therefore, it is important to add it to the documentation.

To undo the "assume-unchanged" flag by running git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file_path>