# Ignore a file from future commits but leave that on repo

Tags: git, github

I have my sitemap.xml file that I want to leave on the repository (as it is continually updated) however ignore it from any future code commits (as I don't want it to be overwritten).

So to do this - from my reading I need to:

1. add the file path into `.gitignore`
2. As it was committed
   initially into the repo I need to remove it from being a tracked
   file so: `git rm --cached <file>`

However will step also remove from the repo? How do I therefore handle this?

Comment: I thought you need to do step 2 as part of the process to stop it being tracked?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18543287/2303202 should do it

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to add `git reset HEAD -- sitemap.xml` in `pre-commit` hook. This hook can be bypassed via `-n` when `git commit` if necessary. And in the server side, a hook is needed to reject any commit that includes changes of sitemap.xml.

But I think there are better solutions. This one needs every developer to be aware not to commit the changes of sitemap.xml.