# How to set a VSPROPS variable only if it does not already exist?

Tags: visual-studio, git, vsprops

Say I've got a `.vsprops` file that is used in a solution. In that file, various variables are defined such as `int_dir` for intermediate build results and `log_dir` for the log results.

Usually, these variables get set to default values (relative to the solution).

For me, I'd like to set these two variables to my ramdisk (`R:`), i.e. no longer

```
$(SolutionDir)\intermediate
```

but

```
R:\myproject\intermediate
```

If I change the `.vsprops` file directly, the source control (Git) will mark it as modified.

Is there a way in VSPROPS so that I could check maybe an environment variable and if this variable is not set, the default is used?

If this is not possible, I'd also be interested in a solution for Git to overcome this (but not `--assume-unchanged` and not `.gitignore` because maybe other changes in that file could be relevant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure Git solution could use a [gitattribute filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728):

[image: content filter]

It would involve a `smudge` script, executed on `git checkout`, which would:

- detect if you want to change `$(SolutionDir)` (for instance, test for an environment variable with the updated path in it)
- detect the right file (`xxx.vsprops.tpl`) content ([the script doesn't know the file names or path it operates on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562523/using-git-to-work-with-subversion-ignoring-modifications-to-tracked-files/2562678#2562678))
- generate the actual  `.vsprops` from a `.vsprops.tpl` (template file) which is the one being versioned (the `.vsprops` is no longer versioned)

You can add a `clean` script which would preserve (on `git commit`) all the modification done in the `.vsprops` file back to the `.vsprops.tpl`, except for the `$(SolutionDir)` line.