# Ignore local changes to a file already in GIT repo

Tags: git

I have a GIT repo. Most the files ill work on in a normal way. However a few files I need to change locally but I dont want to ever push these changes to the repo, they are for my local set up only. How can I do this?

Comment: A common solution is also to have e.g. `config.example.ini` as a tracked file in the repository, and the user (or you in this case) is expected to copy that to just `config.ini` to apply the configuration locally.

Comment: That wont work for me as the "config.ini" is already in the repo and I cant change its filename.

Comment: had a similar problem (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968865/how-to-set-a-vsprops-variable-only-if-it-does-not-already-exist) and ended up using filters. Once you've got the hang, they're pretty cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can:

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged <filename>
```

To temporarily ignore changes. https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html#_using_8220_assume_unchanged_8221_bit

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git update-index`, in this form:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged my.properties
```

Git will then no longer check the working copy for changes to `my.properties`.  To re-commence tracking of changes to this file, perform the reverse:

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged my.properties
```

More detail in the [official documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-update-index.html).