# Git: Pull new changes for file but ignore local changes

Tags: git

I'm wondering if there's a way to continue to track a particular file on a remote branch, but to have your local machine ignore any local changes you make to it (for example, a configuration file or something like that).

Comment: what about conflicts ?

Comment: It needs some research, but you can ignore changes in local files via .gitignore and .git/info/exclude. Not sure how conflicts would be solved when you add tracked file there.

Answer (score 3):

I use `.template` files.

You can store Your configuration file with `.template` suffix in repository and create local one without it (and add it to .gitignore)

For example, after You just cloned repo, You have

```
$ git clone my_repo
$ ls
myconfig.conf.template .gitignore
   (and .gitignore contains myconfig.conf)
```

After clone, you should copy template file and You can edit config file and don't harm repo

```
$ cp myconfig.conf.template myconfig.conf
$ vim myconfig.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not going to use `.template` files, [filters](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-2.html#Keyword-Expansion) would come in handy. You would set up a `smudge` filter that introduces your changes in the working copy and a `clean` filter that is run before any `git diff` or `git add`.

The `clean` filter would bring the file back into it's default state, the `smudge` filter would modify the file as you want it to have.

I had similar needs some time ago and use filters since then ([How to set a VSPROPS variable only if it does not already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968865/how-to-set-a-vsprops-variable-only-if-it-does-not-already-exist)).