# Cloning a github repo, making changes, and pushing all but one of the changes back

Tags: git, maven, github

I'd like to clone a github repo and make a few changes to it.  I'd like to submit pull requests to pull those changes to the original repo.  All pretty standard stuff.

However, there's one change that I do NOT want to go back to the original repo.  I'd like to modify the maven artifact id for my clone so that it's not in the same namespace as the original, but obviously I don't want to push that change to the original.

What's the easiest way for me to set up a clone so that I can change the maven artifact ID and not have to worry about accidentally pushing that change to the original when I push my other changes?

Comment: I would temporarily add the specific project/pom.xml to `~/.gitignore_global`, however, this also ignore other changes in the pom.xml. Does this meet your requirements?

Comment: that could work.  not ideal, but might be good enough

Comment: If you do use git to ignore the pom.xml, change `.git/info/exclude` instead , which works like `.gitignore` but is repository-specific and also "[specific to one user's workflow](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I went with was to ignore the file(s) locally in my repo using `.git/info/exclude` as per the comments.

Comment: Simpler solution than my answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

One way to automate that is to have a script:

- modify that maven id for you on `git checkout`
- restore the original id for you on `git commit`

Use for that a [gitattribute filter driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316677/can-git-automatically-switch-between-spaces-and-tabs/2316728#2316728) (your script will have to recognize the *content* of the pom.xml to modify, [since they won't have the name or path of the files they can change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562523/using-git-to-work-with-subversion-ignoring-modifications-to-tracked-files/2562678#2562678))

[image]